# ssh/authorized_keys with a hostname in the 'from' directive

Tags: ssh, dns

I am configuring sshd to allow me to initiate a backup that needs to be done with the root account and started remotely, so I'm trying to lock this down as much as possible.

I have enabled root login only with public keys and only with forced commands. The root authorized_keys file contains the public key, the backup command, and a list of allowed IPs. I can add `UseDNS` to the sshd config to enable hostname lookup, but this seems to be issuing a reverse lookup on the connecting IP to match hostnames, instead of querying the allowed hostname to match the IPs. The result of this is that my IP resolves to the generic hostname published by my ISP, instead of the hostname that I keep updated with my IP. Is there a way to use my FQDN or do I just need to stick to the IP?

/etc/sshd_config:

```
PermitRootLogin forced-commands-only
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no 
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
UseDNS yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
AddressFamily inet
```

/root/.ssh/authorized_keys:

```
from="dynamic.example.com",command="/backup_script.sh" ssh-rsa AAABEQ9c42....
```

/var/log/auth.log:

```
Authentication tried for root with correct key but not 
from a permitted host (host=ip68-9-123-123.ri.ri.cox.net, ip=68.9.123.123).
```

```
# nslookup dynamic.example.com
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   dynamic.example.com
Address: 68.9.123.123
```

Not using `UseDNS` results in this not so helpful message:

/var/log/auth.log:

```
Authentication tried for root with correct key but not 
from a permitted host (host=68.9.123.123, ip=68.9.123.123).
```

I suppose I can just keep the authorized_keys file up to date, but it'd be nicer to just use a FQDN.

Comment: What kind of backup must be started by root that cannot be started with sudo?

Comment: Just FYI, using RSA keys is not really recommended anymore...

Comment: Thanks for the note about RSA. Changing the keys will be easy enough.

Comment: Using sudo would require entering the password… oh, I suppose you're right I could use a sudo configuration that allows executing that script without a password. I do somewhat enjoy being able to control executing the script by specify the one key that is authorized for that though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to know that the `UseDNS` setting on your sshd_config must be set to `yes`, otherwise the server won't bother to check for the reverse. The default seems to be "no", so you end up with something like this:

```
host sshd[875076]: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys:5: Authentication tried for user with correct key but not from a permitted host (host=x.x.x.x, ip=x.x.x.x, required=FQDN).
```

Once you set `UseDNS yes` on your `sshd_config`, don't forget to restart sshd.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a fqdn in your `authorized_keys` file, you will need to ensure that the source ip address reverse-resolves to the desired hostname.  When sshd receives a connection from somewhere else, the only information it has is the ip address; it can only figure out the hostname by performing a reverse DNS query.

Since you're using a dynamic hostname, it is pretty much guaranteed that the ip address from which you are connecting will never resolve to the desired name. Instead, as you have seen, the address will resolve to some sort of static name that is specific to that address.

Your best bet is to either (a) just use an ip address and come up with some mechanism for keeping it up-to-date, or (b) don't rely on information about the originating address as part of your authentication. Instead, use a purpose-specific ssh key or some other solution.

Comment: Thanks. I'd argue that sshd _could_ lookup the FQDN that I've specified and see if the resulting IPs match, but it seems that's not possible here. You're right that I could keep the IP up to date (I could easily script that locally on the remote host). I am indeed using a purpose-specific ssh key already. I'll rethink whether the IP is actually required. Thanks.